# CSS keyframe animation in iOS Safari/Chrome/Firefox flickers/out of sync

Tags: ios, reactjs, css-animations, keyframe

I have a React app with CSS keyframe animations to change the appearance of text, and am changing the font dynamically through JS using setState and setInterval.

I sync the keyframe animation to begin playing at the same time as a call to setInterval, and everything works fine on Chrome/Safari for desktop. On Safari/Chrome/Firefox on iOS, the animation flickers, and is generally out of sync. Interestingly enough, on Safari if I refresh the page after the initial load, everything tends to work fine.

I've read through many threads of similar issues here, but none of the solutions are working for me. I've tried adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`, `body {-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);}`, and trying to add a delay at the beginning of the animation to offset the flickering. Nothing worked.

Here is a live link: https://stoic-khorana-e0bd2c.netlify.com/

And here is the code -- it's a tiny app, basically just a splash page: https://github.com/themarquisdesheric/el4d/tree/master/src

I have a delay for the 'AKA' to show up, then another delay for the name changing to begin.

SCSS:

```
.aka-container {
  .aka { 
    opacity: 0;
    animation: showAKA 400ms 750ms ease-out forwards;
  }

  .name-changer {
    animation: fade 1500ms infinite paused; 

    &.playing { animation-play-state: running; }
  }

}

@keyframes showAKA {
  20%,
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  20%,
  80% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Here is the React component:

```
class NameChanger extends Component {
  state = {
    name: null,
    fontFamily: null,
    index: 0,
    playing: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.setInterval(this.changeName, 1500);
    this.setState({ playing: true });
  }

  changeFont = (index) => {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return 'Sedgwick Ave Display';
      case 1:
        return 'Bangers';
      case 2:
        return 'Luckiest Guy';
      default:
        return 'Bangers';
    }
  };

  changeName = () => {
    const names = ['ol lightsy', 'eladi-da', 'el-40'];
    const { index } = this.state;
    const { changeFont } = this;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      name: names[index],
      fontFamily: changeFont(index),
      index: (index === names.length - 1) 
        ? 0 
        : prevState.index + 1
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { name, fontFamily, playing } = this.state;

    return (
      <span
        className={`name-changer ${playing ? 'playing' : ''}`} 
        style={{ 
          fontFamily,
          position: 'relative',
          top: (name === 'el-40') ? '.25rem' : ''
        }}
      >
        {name}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm wondering why this works fine in Chrome, but bugs out on mobile. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that [iOS pauses timers](https://github.com/benschwarz/gallery-css/issues/7) if it thinks that the page is being scrolled/zoomed. This is true for Safari, Chrome, and Firefox on iOS.

I solved this issue by removing my use of setInterval and achieving the same effect using the `animationiteration` event instead. Apparently the animation's own timer is respected, whereas timers like setInterval are not.

```
class NameChanger extends Component {
  state = {
    name: null,
    fontFamily: null,
    index: 0,
    playing: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { span, changeName } = this;

    span.addEventListener('animationiteration', 
      () => changeName()
    );

    this.setState({ playing: true });
  }

  changeFont = (index) => {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return 'Sedgwick Ave Display';
      case 1:
        return 'Bangers';
      case 2:
        return 'Luckiest Guy';
      default:
        return 'Bangers';
    }
  };

  changeName = () => {
    const names = ['ol lightsy', 'eladi-da', 'el-40', 'elautopilot'];
    const { index } = this.state;
    const { changeFont } = this;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      name: names[index],
      fontFamily: changeFont(index),
      index: (index === names.length - 1) 
        ? 0 
        : prevState.index + 1
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { name, fontFamily, playing } = this.state;

    return (
      <span
        className={`name-changer ${playing ? 'playing' : ''}`} 
        ref={span => this.span = span}
        style={{ 
          fontFamily,
          position: 'relative',
          top: (name === 'el-40') ? '.25rem' : ''
        }}
      >
        {name}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```